# azure secrets store csi driver provider throws Error: secret * not found

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets, kubernetes-csi

Below is my app definition that uses [azure csi store provider](https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/docs/demos/). Unfortunately, this definition throws `Error: secret 'my-kv-secrets' not found` why is that?

#### SecretProviderClass

```yaml
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: my-app-dev-spc
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: my-kv-secrets
    type: Opaque
    data: 
    - objectName: DB-HOST
      key: DB-HOST
  parameters:
    keyvaultName: my-kv-name
    objects: |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: DB-HOST
          objectType: secret
    tenantId: "xxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-rrrr-vvvvvvvv"
```

#### Pod

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: debug
  name: debug
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - sleep
    - 1d
    name: debug
    image: alpine
    env:
    - name: DB_HOST
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: my-kv-secrets
          key: DB-HOST
  volumes:
  - name: kv-secrets
    csi:
      driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
      readOnly: true
      volumeAttributes:
        secretProviderClass: my-app-dev-spc
      nodePublishSecretRef:
        name: my-sp-secrets
```

Answer (score 6):

It turned out that secrets store csi  works only with `volumeMounts`. So if you forget to specify it in your yaml definition then it will not work! Below is fix.

#### Pod

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: debug
  name: debug
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - sleep
    - 1d
    name: debug
    image: alpine
    env:
    - name: DB_HOST
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: my-kv-secrets
          key: DB-HOST
    volumeMounts:
    - name: kv-secrets
      mountPath: /mnt/kv_secrets
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: kv-secrets
    csi:
      driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
      readOnly: true
      volumeAttributes:
        secretProviderClass: my-app-dev-spc
      nodePublishSecretRef:
        name: my-sp-secrets
```

Comment: You saved me hours and hours of searching. Should be voted with at least +100! Thank you!